# Word 2010 showing formula for Table of Content and not Table of Content

Tags: microsoft-word

At some point while creating a document in Word 2010, the formulas for TOC and SUMs began showing as formulas, NOT the actual Table of Contents or number of the sum.  I think I hit a combination of keys that switched to this view and I cannot get it back to normal.  If I can't get to the Table of Contents, I cannot make necessary changes. How do I go back so I can work in correct view?  The only place they show up as correct is when I want to print, then the actual content shows but I cannot change it in print view.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pressing <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>F9</kbd> will toggle between showing the formula, and showing their result.

Comment: THANK YOU!  I knew it had to be an easy fix, I just couldn't find it.

Comment: Nice nice nice.

Comment: Nice. And also, random.